# Style DatePickerDialog selector background

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

Does anyone know how to style the black boxes surrounding the date selectors so that they match the background of my DatePickerDialog?
[image: Broken DatePickerDialog]

For reference here is the style I'm using for AlertDialogs:

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/group_blue_800</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.2</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Do you want to keep using the pre-lollipop design or want the material one? I backported the official, framework (8.0, Oreo) version of the `DatePickerDialog` and `TimePickerDialog` which you can find here: [https://github.com/Gericop/DateTimePicker](https://github.com/Gericop/DateTimePicker) and makes the pickers have the material design on API 14+ devices.

Comment: I'm already using the new material design version for devices at API level 21+, but for some reason my existing styles resulted in this behavior for the pre-lollipop design. I resolved it by creating a brand new style just to be used by pre-lollipop devices which you'll find below. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: That's why I'm saying that if you use material design throughout your app, you might want to consider "upgrading" the framework version to the backported one so that it would use the material design on all API levels instead of 21+ only, but the choice is yours. I made this backport because the old holo styled dialogs looked pretty ugly with the otherwise fully materialized app of mine.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean! I'll be sure to check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a standalone style for DatePickers/TimePickers for pre-Lollipop devices:

```
<style name="PreLollipopDatePickerStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.2</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/secondary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/group_blue_800</item>
    </style>
```

I then create a DatePicker/TimePicker using the constructor where you pass a theme resource ID for pre-Lollipop devices:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
if (AndroidUtils.isLollipop()) {
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
        getActivity(),
        new EndDateTimeSelectedListener(),
        endDateTimeExclusive.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        endDateTimeExclusive.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        endDateTimeExclusive.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
} else {
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
        getActivity(),
        R.style.PreLollipopDatePickerStyle,
        new EndDateTimeSelectedListener(),
        endDateTimeExclusive.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        endDateTimeExclusive.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        endDateTimeExclusive.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

datePickerDialog.show();
```